# your account is suspended and therefore we bork orthography

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension, wording

That’s what you see instead of message textbox in the chat when you are suspended:

[image]

What? If it is a complete sentence (which it is; there is a finite verb in there), then capitalize it. If it is not a complete sentence, then remove the dot.

Comment: Stop being suspended and the issue goes away

Comment: You're *that* offended by something like this?  Really?  How can you be on the internet without going insane if you consider something like this to be seriously offensive?

Comment: @Servy No, did I say so? I'm not. Just it is a bug :)

Comment: You mean orthography, not grammar.

Comment: @Seven Ok, doesn't sound well however :D

Comment: @nicael No, you're quite right. Criticising grammar has a tradition of righteous fury behind it, but orthography being much more fluid and subject to local conventions and style guides means criticising it just doesn't have the same impact...

Comment: The dot is not meant to end a complete sentence.  It's meant to show the finality of the banning. ***your account is suspended on the parent site and cannoth chat for 20 days PERIOD*** is how it should be read. ;)

Comment: @Adam LOL okay, next time I'm suspended, I'll get it different :D

Comment: Shouldn't your title here have a dot at the end?

Comment: @Josh stripped, unfortunately :(

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: English orthography is very resistant to change, whether you compare it to other orthographies or grammar. There is a very small portion that is subject to style guides and locality but everything else is undisputed and very stable (which is why English orthography is so horribly unphonemic). And capitalising full sentences and ending them with a period is among the things everybody agrees on.

Comment: Exclamation point works, maybe?

Comment: Orthography? Perhaps you meant typography?

Comment: @Josh WAIT, it is so unnoticeable :D maybe no?

Comment: Whatever you want; it was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft If we were speaking of passages of formal English prose, yes. We're not though.

Comment: OMG the sky is falling..... yeesh...

Comment: Are question bans disabled on Meta?? If not... I can see one coming soon :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I was already banned once, so nope. That's only on per-site metas :D

Comment: can we request one?

Comment: @santiago *you*? No, *you* can't. Requesting the ban requires more repz. :P

Comment: oh well, downvoted instead

Comment: Sometimes I wonder.... are you doing this on purpose??

Comment: @Sha um. What exactly?

Comment: That answers my question - you're not doing it on purpose. Oh well... too bad many people already cast automatic downvote on your reports even when they're valid.

Comment: @Sha bzzzz. Demistify please. What am I suspected to do on purpose? Getting all those down votes, eh?

Comment: Reporting totally minor bugs that by now you are fully aware will get you rain of downvotes. If nothing else, I hope you have an umbrella with you... :D

Answer (score 14):

Nicael, it is nice to have you back.

Although you are totally right on this being something to fix, I do need to tell you something.

The current votes on your question, and your previous questions, show that most users in this community don't think such bug reports are useful. The ongoing list of typographical issues that are not that relevant compared to the things that to matter.

See it as a politician that keeps asking the same unimportant questions in Congress. They don't like it, and so do a lot of users here.

I am not reflecting my personal opinion here, but it might be better to contribute with content that does matter.

Comment: Well said, and very politely too

Comment: Ever considered getting into politics, Patrick? ;)